# Does it make any difference which class is target class in a binary classifier with balanced data?

Tags: classification, binary-data

The title says it all. If you are working on a two class classification problem with 50% of instances from each class does it matter which of the two classes is the positive class? Does the classification algorithm used affect the answer?

Comment: What you consider positive is entirely semantic. It makes no difference to the underlying algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any data-driven classification approaches where the class labels have any effect on the resulting class decisions; this is the case even if the training set is unbalanced.  Although not usually explicit, that the results are independent under permutations of the class labels is an essential part of how these algorithms are set up.

If you're not doing a strictly data-driven problem, the identification of class labels might contain information that could affect your results.  For example, if the "positive" cases are, say, positive for some disease, and your "negative" cases are from a random sample of healthy people, *and you knew that the occurence of the disease were rare*, you may modify how you set up and use the results of any classification scheme.  However, this relies on the existence of domain specific knowledge separate from the labels themselves.